# MVVMCross View blocked by sqlite call

Tags: mvvmcross

I am trying to build a fairly simple sqlite database based mobile app using mvvmcross and Portable class libraries. The database I have running is fairly large so querying it takes enough time where I don't want the UI to get blocked while running queries.

The way I currently have it set up is in a few classes based on the mvvmcross n+1 tutorials  [n=10](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n10-sqlite-persistent-data-storage-n1.html) tutorial. I have two services that manage the look-ups for the two entities.

How can I perform these database calls on a separate thread and have the view be updated when completed. I assume that this capability exists within mvvmcross I just haven't been able to track down the documentation or any tutorials on it specifically.

Any help pointing me to the right direction would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
JH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portable class libraries do give you access to the `ThreadPool` - so you could use that to marshall the work onto a background thread? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx

---

Alternatively, if you have a setup/configuration which allows the TPL to be used in your library, then you could use the `TaskFactory` or `async` and `await` to provide some background threading - this is probably the better long-term route, but getting this setup and working initially may take longer as Xamarin's async support is very new and it's PCL support is changing.

Comment: OK thanks, I will go explore ThreadPool first. But I am using the same configuration as you are using in all of you N+1 tutorials (which are awesome by the way) is the TPL available with that setup?